# How to read efficiently a csv list in particular defined sort order?

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, collections

I am reading a `CSV` and mapping it to a `List<SomeBean>` using `ICsvBeanReader`.

*csv:*

```
someName,someNumber,report,env,dir
TEST1,111111111111,DES,T,LAS
TEST1,111111111111,INV,T,LAS
TEST1,111111111111,DES,T,FIRS
TEST1,111111111111,INV,T,FIRS
TEST1,111111111111,ORD,P,FIRS
TEST1,111111111111,ORD,P,LAS
```

Once I have the `List<SomeBean>`  dataList, I am running nested for loop to get what I am intended to achieve.

*Defined Order:*

```
{1-FIRS, 2-LAS}
{1-P, 2-T}
{1-ORD, 2-DES, 3-INV}
```

*Expected:*
A map of 'someNumber' and combination of report,env,dir (In a defined Orders).

```
111111111111,ORD-P-FIRS
111111111111,DES-T-FIRS
111111111111,INV-T-FIRS
111111111111,ORD-P-LAS
111111111111,DES-T-LAS
111111111111,INV-T-LAS
```

*CODING:*

Get Order:

```
Map<Integer, String> dirOrder = {1-FIRS, 2-LAS}; // getting from defined config
Map<Integer, String> envOrder = {1-P, 2-T}; // getting from defined config
Map<Integer, String> reportOrder = {1-ORD, 2-DES, 3-INV};// getting from defined config
```

Run loops for preparing map:

```
MultiValuedMap < String, String > mapProperOrder = new ArrayListValuedHashMap < > ();

        for (Map.Entry < Integer, String > directionEntry: dirOrder.entrySet()) {
         String directionValue = directionEntry.getValue();

         for (Map.Entry < Integer, String > envirionmentEntry: envOrder.entrySet()) {
          String envirionmentValue = envirionmentEntry.getValue();

          for (Map.Entry < Integer, String > reportTypeEntry: reportOrder.entrySet()) {
           String reportTypeValue = reportTypeEntry.getValue();

           for (SomeBean someBean: (List < SomeBean > ) someList) {

            String num = someBean.getNum();
            String dir = someBean.getDir();
            String env = someBean.getEnv();
            String report = someBean.getReport);

           boolean directionCheck = dir.equalsIgnoreCase(directionValue) ? true : false;
           boolean envirionmentCheck = env.equalsIgnoreCase(envirionmentValue) ? true : false;
           boolean reportTypeCheck = report.equalsIgnoreCase(reportTypeValue) ? true : false;

           if (directionCheck && envirionmentCheck && reportTypeCheck) {
            mapProperOrder.put(num, report + "-" + env + "-" + dir);
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

This code does its job, but what if I have a multiple 'someNumber' in a CSV, It will be not efficient to run a nested for loop for all the records.

Please help me to write a simple yet efficient way to process this.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would implement `Comparable` interface in `SomeBean` if this order is default order application-wide or a custom `Comparator` otherwise.

The implementation might look as it follows:

```
public int compare(SomeBean o1, SomeBean o2) {
    Map<String, Integer> firstLevel = new HashMap<>();
    firstLevel.put("FIRS", 1);
    firstLevel.put("LAS", 2);


    int cmp = firstLevel.get(o1.getDir()).compareTo(firstLevel.get(o2.getDir()));

    if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
    }

    Map<String, Integer> secondLevel = new HashMap<>();
    secondLevel.put("P", 1);
    secondLevel.put("T", 2);

    cmp = secondLevel.get(o1.getEnv()).compareTo(secondLevel.get(o2.getEnv()));

    if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
    }

    Map<String, Integer> thirdLevel = new HashMap<>();
    thirdLevel.put("ORD", 1);
    thirdLevel.put("DES", 2);
    thirdLevel.put("INV", 3);

    return thirdLevel.get(o1.getReport()).compareTo(thirdLevel.get(o2.getReport()));

}
```